# SharePoint 2013 - How can I disable the editform(no metadata insertion) during the upload of document in a library?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I need to disable the Edit Form(no metadata insertion) during the upload of document in a library by PowerShell or event Receiver.

Thanks in advance.